# how to get rid of awstat www-data daemon?

Tags: debian, cron, daemon, awstats

I have successfully installed awstats on my webserver. I have created a cron job that runs as root every third hour. And it works perfectly, but i keep receiving "mails" every 10 minutes saying that www-data tried to update and did not have the right permissions for it.

```
Message 58:
From www-data@cosmos Sun Aug 21 23:20:02 2016
Envelope-to: root@cosmos
Delivery-date: Sun, 21 Aug 2016 23:20:02 +0200
From: root@cosmos (Cron Daemon)
To: root@cosmos
Subject: Cron  [ -x /usr/share/awstats/tools/update.sh ] && /usr/share/awstats/tools/update.sh
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: 
X-Cron-Env: 
X-Cron-Env: 
X-Cron-Env: 
X-Cron-Env: 
Date: Sun, 21 Aug 2016 23:20:02 +0200

Error while processing /etc/awstats/awstats.****.***.conf
Create/Update database for config "/etc/awstats/awstats.****.***.conf" by AWStats version 7.2 (build 1.992)
>From data in log file "/var/log/apache2/access.log"...
Error: Couldn't open server log file "/var/log/apache2/access.log" : Permission denied
Setup ('/etc/awstats/awstats.****.***.conf' file, web server or permissions) may be wrong.
Check config file, permissions and AWStats documentation (in 'docs' directory).
Error while processing /etc/awstats/awstats.conf
Create/Update database for config "/etc/awstats/awstats.conf" by AWStats version 7.2 (build 1.992)
>From data in log file "/var/log/apache2/access.log"...
Error: Couldn't open server log file "/var/log/apache2/access.log" : Permission denied
Setup ('/etc/awstats/awstats.conf' file, web server or permissions) may be wrong.
Check config file, permissions and AWStats documentation (in 'docs' directory).

(END)
```

The problem is that i can`t find the cron job and delete it. I am aware that it is possible to stop getting "mails", but i want to stop the process from running every 10 minutes. Do anyone know where this cron job lives? Or how to stop it?

BTW: i am running debian 8.2

Comment: Check in `/etc/cron.d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use dpkg to see the package contents, you will see a cron file:

```
$ dpkg -L awstats
/etc/cron.d/awstats
```

Comment out the lines in that file, eg. with

```
sed -r -i "s/^([^#])/#\1/" /etc/cron.d/awstats
```